Filtered by token holder
I swapped BNB BEP-20 for Bera through Pancakeswap v3. The transaction shows up as valid but i can't transfer/receive my Bera to/in my wallet,
There is a message in bold that says: Filtered by token holder. Can that be the problem? If so, what can i do to get access and being able to transfer them?
Tnx.

"FILTERED BY TOKEN HOLDER" is used to show the transfers of a particular token by token holder address i.e., any address holding that particular token.


If you want to transfer the Bera token using your MetaMask wallet, then you might have to add that token using its token contract address to your MetaMask that you can do by following How to add a custom token steps mentioned in MetaMask docs.

SYED ASAD KAZMI, I've added token to my metamask wallet before. It didn't help. I can see my contract on bscscan, but I don't know a reason why it didn't come to me

@Adrian, Can you share the contract address?

SYED ASAD KAZMI ok, here it is: 0x3EA78E60e1C2142c16Ed2B169FaD6fE95F91e0DB

So, you’re saying that you haven’t received this Bera token. Can you share the transaction hash where that contract has transferred tokens to your wallet?

Where I can find it?

I'm a newbie at this

No worries, @Adrian. As, you’ve mentioned in your question "The transaction shows up as valid but i can't transfer/receive my Bera to/in my wallet". So, where have you seen that transaction?

SYED ASAD KAZMI, if I understand you right, I've seen that I have that smart contract at history of transactions in my wallet. Then I came to bscscan, where was all information about it

Now I'm starting to think that I got scammed, but maybe not

As you've mentioned "Then I came to bscscan, where was all information about it". So, were you able to find any transaction on BscScan, that was by that contract address to your wallet address?

Basically, are you able to find your wallet address in any of the token transactions ?

SYED ASAD KAZMI, yes, I'm able to find my wallet address in this contract into "events" as recepient

Nevermind bro. It was a scam. Thanks for your help

That’s unfortunate bro. Sorry for your loss. Be safe!
